# Jackson Deserialization - Wrong body types sucessfully deserializing

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to validate a POST request to my REST controller, a have some properties and validations on my DTO class:

*EmployeeDTOInput.java*

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class EmployeeDTOInput {

  @NotBlank("name must not be blank!")
  private String name;

  @DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message = "salary must be greather than or equal to $0.01!")
  private BigDecimal salary;

  @NotNull("commission elegible must not be null!")
  private boolean commissionElegible;
}
```

Also, have a valid checker on the controller:

```
@PostMapping
public EmployeeDTO store(@RequestBody @Valid EmployeeDTOInput employeeDTOInput) {
 // Controller logic
}
```

Writing some tests, I figured out that, if my JSON request object have this syntax, and it works fine:

```
{
  name: 12345,
  salary: "30000.50"
}
```

Is there some way to reject this kind of request, I mean, accept only with the 100% coherence of JSON property types according to the actual DTO properties, accepting only float format to `salary`, string format to `name` and not ignoring the `commissionElegible`?

I've tryied to add some Jackson properties on application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-ignored-properties=true
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-invalid-subtype=true
```

And some Jackson annotations on the DTO class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class EmployeeDTOInput {

  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
  @NotBlank("name must not be blank!")
  private String name;
  
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_FLOAT)
  @DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message = "salary must be greather than or equal to $0.01!")
  private BigDecimal salary;

  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.BOOLEAN)
  @NotNull("commission elegible must not be null!")
  private boolean commissionElegible;
}
```

But the request still works.

Is there some way to prevent this 'wrong' deserialization and configure it to throw an Exception?

Comment: How are you sending request in the test? can you add your test code please. Please comment on the spring-boot version etc

Comment: I'm using RestAssured and Matchers, the test itself don't pass as expected to, but I'm not with problem on tests, the problem is currently on the POST request, that is allowing a body type that should be interpreted as wrong by the Server, I can reproduce it with any REST Client. Using Spring Boot 2.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to configure ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS property of ObjectMapper.

It can be achieved by changing setting in application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.allow-coercion-of-scalars=false
```

And here is the JavaDoc:

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS

Comment: It works!! Really helped, but as JavaDoc says: It actually excludes this feature to String properties, but now, the inverse is working fine. Really thanks!

Comment: If you are interested in the background or more details the issue has been discussed in the jackson-databind github.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/796